# Webpack Imported Module is not a function

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a repository (in a MenuRepository.js file) that has an index() method, when I try to call that method from my mounted() function in my Vue instance, I get the following error

[image]

This has been working before, So I can't imagine what happened..
This is the code of my Vue instance.

```
class MenuRepository {
  async index () {
    const result = await Nova.request().get('/')
    return result.data
  }
}

export default MenuRepository
```

And this is the Vue file

```
import MenuRepository from '../repositories/MenuRepository'

export default {
  async mounted () {
    try {
      const menus = await MenuRepository.index()
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `index` is an instance method, however you are calling it on the class not an instance of the class.  Unless I am missing something I think you should either make index static or create a new instance of the class, depending on what your intention is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution

The issue was that it wasn't being instantiated.

Use

```
export default new MenuRepository()
```

Instead of

```
export default MenuRepository
```